# How to run boot repair when Ubuntu is inaccessible, and conflicts in BIOS settings? (Dual Booting)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I've got a computer set up to dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 10, which was working fine for several months. Recently, Ubuntu started Blackscreening when launched via Grub or BIOS boot override (likely cause is a windows 10 update).

I've flashed a USB with Boot-Repair, and can successfully boot via Live USB. However, Boot-Repair requires booting with CSM/Legacy modes disabled. When I disable CSM in BIOS I get an error on boot to the tune of "VGA Card not Compatible with UEFI, CSM settings have been changed for compatibility" which seems to automatically re-enable CSM without any option to disable it, preventing me from using Boot repair.

What do I do?

EDIT: My Graphics card doesn't support UEFI mode. I have no idea how I'm supposed to run Boot-Repair now.

Excerpt of Boot-Repair Boot Info Summary:

```
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdd: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on sdc4
OS#2:   Windows 8 or 10 on sda3

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to unsign) and reinstall the grub-efi of
sdc4,
using the following options:  sdc3/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode. 64bits detected. Please use this software in a 64bits session. (Please use Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd) which contains a 64bits-compatible version of this software.) This will enable this feature.

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS entry (sdc3/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)
The boot of your PC is in BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode. You may want to retry after changing it to UEFI mode.
```

Comment: Old Computer? Check Bios Battery.

Comment: That is a new error to me. What brand/model system & what video card/chip? Have you updated UEFI to latest version available. Did you install driver from Ubuntu repository? Are both installs UEFI. Are you running bit older Boot-Repair from ISO, or from Ubuntu live installer using ppa? Better to use ppa. Can you post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. https://windowsreport.com/vga-not-supported-by-uefi-driver/

Comment: Resetting the bios battery did nothing unfortunately. 

It’s an Asus Rog mobo running an i5-4670k and an R9 290X. Bios is up to date as of a couple of months ago. Both installs should be UEFI, though I can’t check the Linux install now. I used the ISO, but allowed it to update in the live environment. 

I can’t check it for whatever reason but this should be the summary. https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/vNMx4ctSSC/ EDIT: Worth noting Linux is on a partitioned hard drive with windows files, but isn’t on the boot drive AFAIK. Could be a mistake.